# How to use Curly brace as left and right boundary of Div

Tags: html, css

I have created a small instance of Curly brace (left) with below program

```css
span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.left-brace-tl {
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-right:-6px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.left-brace-tr {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.left-brace-bl {
    margin-top: -4px;
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-right:-6px;
}

.left-brace-br {
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span class="left-brace-tl"></span>
<span class="left-brace-tr"></span><br />
<span class="left-brace-bl"></span>
<span class="left-brace-br"></span>
</div>
```

While as stand-alone basis it appears good, but I want to use left (and right) curly braces as left and right border of a rectangular div

I really appreciate for any pointer on how can I move forward to implement such

Comment: Have you tried using flex-box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@laiju's solution is good. I just tried to approach this in another way by rotating the left curly brace `180` degrees. I have used `flex` to align the border `divs`. Also I changed the `span` height to make the borders responsive with the wrapping `div's` **dynamic height**.

```css
span {
  width: 10px;
  height: calc(50% - 10px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.rect {
  display: flex;
}

.left-brace-tl {
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: -6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.left-brace-tr {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

.left-brace-bl {
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.left-brace-br {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.right-border {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">

  <div class="left-border">
    <span class="left-brace-tl"></span>
    <span class="left-brace-tr"></span><br />
    <span class="left-brace-bl"></span>
    <span class="left-brace-br"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="right-border">
    <span class="left-brace-tl"></span>
    <span class="left-brace-tr"></span><br />
    <span class="left-brace-bl"></span>
    <span class="left-brace-br"></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this by using content

```css
.sample:before {
  content: "{";
  font-size: 42px;
}

.sample:after {
  content: "}";
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
  Sample Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a proper solution, as it only gives a curly bracket not a curly brace, but it has the advantage of being a simple CSS-only solution that requires no extra markup in the HTML.  Sometimes that's enough of an advantage to justify only using a bracket rather than the desired brace.

```html
<div style="width: 250px; margin: 1em auto" class="lbracket rbracket">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
  consequat.
</div>
```

The inline CSS on the `<div>` is just as an example.  The important bit is the `lbracket` and `rbracket` classes:

```css
.lbracket {
  border-left: thin solid black;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
}
.rbracket {
  border-right: thin solid black;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.75em;
}
```

This produces something like the following:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

A nice quick solution would be to `float: left` all of your content so that it lines up horizontally.

```html
<!-- Your original brace, with 'float: left' added. -->
<div style="float: left;">
  <span class="left-brace-tl"></span>
  <span class="left-brace-tr"></span><br />
  <span class="left-brace-bl"></span>
  <span class="left-brace-br"></span>
</div>
<!-- Here is the content you want in the brace.
     I have set the height to 80px because it
     is roughly the size of your brace.
     The background-color property is just for show. -->
<div style="float: left; background-color: lightblue; height: 80px">
  You can put anything you like within this div now.
</div>
<!-- You would put your right brace here. 
     You should be able to create a right brace
     in a similar way to how you created the
     left brace. Just follow the same process.
     You will end up including it as follows. -->
<!--
<div style="float: left;">
  <span class="left-brace-tl"></span>
  <span class="left-brace-tr"></span><br />
  <span class="left-brace-bl"></span>
  <span class="left-brace-br"></span>
</div>
-->
```

[Here's a screenshot of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7hJ.png)

On another note you may want to extract the inline properties into some CSS classes. You may also want to consider not redefining span in your original CSS because it will make you run into issues down the line.